# Использовать разные стили на одинаковые элементы (Wordpress)

Tags: css, wordpress

Использую тему Onepress для Wordpress. Вставил блок с счетчиками - 4 штуки. Для них нужно прописать разные стили (цвет, картинку before). Но проблема заключается в том, что все блоки по структуре одинаковые и имеют одни и те же классы. Использую first, last, n child, но не работает наверно из-за того что они все в разных блоках находятся. Как правильно присвоить каждому счетчику собственные стили?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Укажите больше инфы: куда добавляете код счетчика - это виджет, контент или что-то еще. Приложите участок кода

Comment: если у вас проблема со стилизацией, то неплохо было бы приложить разметку, для которой вы пишете стили

Comment: Приложил картинку к вопросу. Получается в теме onepress выбираю блок section counter. Там соответственно добавляю 4 счетчика. Все они имеют одинаковую структуру как на картинке. Возможности добавить дополнительный класс к счетчику нет.

Comment: А чем реализован Section Counter? Виджет, какой-то плагин типа Visual Composser или это базовый функционал? Я не вижу этого в базовом функционале

Comment: Уже разобрался, это у вас базовый функционал темы, но сначала необходимо импортировать Sample Data и потом смотреть в кастомайзере Section Counter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Посмотрите в настройках блока, возможно можно указать дополнительный класс или ID блока.
2. Если нет, пробуйте дополнительно обернуть в какой-то контейнер с уникальным
   классом или ID

   ```
   <div id="counter1" class="counter">...</div>
   ```

id - уникальный, class - если у вас есть какие-то общие стили, хотя у вас возможно уже есть там какие-то классы

Попробуйте такой вариант

```
    section#counter .container .row > div:nth-child(1) .counter__number {
        color: red;
    }

    section#counter .container .row > div:nth-child(2) .counter__number {
        color: blue;
    }

    section#counter .container .row > div:nth-child(3) .counter__number {
        color: black;
    }

    section#counter .container .row > div:nth-child(4) .counter__number {
        color: green;
    }
```

Comment: Да наверняка там есть настройки блока, с помощью которых можно добавить класс.

Comment: Нету такой функции добавить дополнительный класс. А как можно редактировать html структуру блока?

Comment: А как вам это объяснить, не видя с чем вы вообще работаете? Wordpress и тема Onepress абстрактные понятия

Comment: я приложил код блока, таких 4

Comment: Обновил ответ, попробуйте так, а дальше можете делать как вам удобно

Comment: Работает, огромное спасибо

Comment: Если ответ вам был полезен отметьте его, чтоб закрыть вопрос. Таким образом люди будут видеть где есть ответ на их вопрос в аналогичной ситуации

Comment: @WalterScott не спасибо, а лучше галку постаьте к ответу. Человек для вас старался, время тратил. Отметьте его труд баллами репутации. Кроме того, ответ правильный и может быть полезен другим пользователям. Им легче будет ориентироваться, видя принятый ответ.